# use awk to transform an 'n column' csv dataset to an '(n-1) column' dataset

Tags: csv, awk, sed, dataset

I have a data transformation problem of changing a graph dataset to a transactional dataset. Should I use AWK or use a different language?

Sample csv input with first row header and desired output.

input.csv

```
TO, FROM, WEIGHT 
Bob Jones, Tom P. Fisher, 1 
Adam Left, Bob Jones, 3
```

output.csv

```
ID, TARGET
1, Bob Jones
1, Tom P. Fisher
2, Adam Left
2, Bob Jones
3, Adam Left
3, Bob Jones
4, Adam Left
4, Bob Jones
```

Comment: where does `ID 3` come from?

Comment: I changed the weight to 3 limit confusion about the 'weight' column. The 'Adam to Bob' connection happens 3 times

Comment: Your second table makes no sense based on your original data still....

Comment: Adam Left and Bob Jones have 3 connections and therefor need to be listed 3 times in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another in awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=", "                 # set delimiters
    print "ID", "TARGET"        # output header
} 
$NF~/[0-9]+/ {                  # process records which end in a value
    for(i=1;i<=$NF;i++) {       # loop $NF many times
        c++                     # counter
        for(j=1;j<NF;j++)       # for each name 
            print c, $j         # print count and name
    }
}' file
ID, TARGET
1, Bob Jones
1, Tom P. Fisher
2, Adam Left
2, Bob Jones
3, Adam Left
3, Bob Jones
4, Adam Left
4, Bob Jones
```

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F',[[:space:]]*' 'BEGIN{ print "ID, TARGET" }NR>1{ id_cnt+=$3; id=(NR==2)? 1 : id_cnt-$3; 
     for(i=id;i<=id_cnt;i++) printf("%d, %s\n%d, %s\n",i,$1,i,$2) }' file
```

The output:

```
ID, TARGET
1, Bob Jones
1, Tom P. Fisher
1, Adam Left
1, Bob Jones
2, Adam Left
2, Bob Jones
3, Adam Left
3, Bob Jones
4, Adam Left
4, Bob Jones
```

Comment: I just noticed that the ID 1 is repeated in four lines.

Answer (score 0):

Where `ad.data` is your data file and `ad.csv` is your output file.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {print $3, $1\n$2, $1}' ad.data>ad.csv
```

Comment: Did you see that I changed the weight to 3?

Comment: I am getting an error. awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1

Comment: you have to run this in the directory containing `ad.data` whatever your data file is.